# Why Flask removes + characters from request.post

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am developing a microservice using flask but I encountered a problem. When I read data from my `request.form` it turns out that all the plus characters (+) have been removed.

I can't change either the content-type header or the way of sending data.

Minimal example:

```
response = requests.post(
    url='http://0.0.0.0:6666/test',
    data='aaaaa+bbbbb',
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
)
```

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def update_text():
    print(request.form)

    return Response()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=6666)
```

When I run this example, `request.form` is `ImmutableMultiDict([('aaaaa bbbbb', '')])` insted of `ImmutableMultiDict([('aaaaa+bbbbb', '')])`.

Is there any way I can correct this on the flask side? And, above all, why is this happening?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You have specified that you are delivering content using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. URLs cannot contain spaces. According to [url encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) rules, `+` represents a space character. If you want a `+`, you would use `%2B`.

If you were actually submitting an HTML form, this encoding would be taken care of for you. When you testing it with a direct `POST` request, you need to perform the encoding yourself. For example:

```py
import urllib.parse

response = requests.post(
    url='http://0.0.0.0:6666/test',
    data=urllib.parse.quote('aaaaa+bbbbb'),
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
)
```

Comment: URLs cannot contain spaces -> Ok, right. But why is this affecting data/form of the request?
Unfortunately, I cannot change the way the data is sent in any way. This includes adding encoding :/.
I need a solution on the flask side

Comment: "But why is this affecting data/form of the request?" Sorry, I tried to make it clear in my answer: it affects your request because you have declared that you are encoding data using URL encoding (your are sending data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). That means you need to respect URL encoding rules.

Comment: Okey, now is everything clear.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out solution:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def update_text():
    data = request.get_data()
    print(request.data) # now I have correct data (with +) in this attr. Before without function above, this was empty. 

    return Response()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=6666)
```